# How to prevent Reload activity in android?

Tags: android

Have two activity A,B :Activity A contains list,onclick of list am taking to B activity.In B activity i have 3 buttons let it[B,q,r] on click of each button am taking to new activity loading data from server.So i dont want to reload everytime that data.And from any of these p,q,r on back pressed i want to take him back to Activity A

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reloading the data, you need to separate your data in a different class from your UI activities. This way, no matter how many times you call the same `Activity`, the data will be loaded only once.

If you want to go back to the activity A, you have to modify intent flags before calling any other activities from A :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```